# Import Typescript file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension and I'm trying to import a Typescript file in Javascript.
Both files are next to each others.

I'm importing it this way:

```
import { ApiParsing } from './ApiParsing.ts';
```

When I'm using the extension I have the following error:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript cannot be executed from a browser / node.js environment directly. At first you have to `transpile` it into native javascript. To do this you will need to execute `tsc`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html

Typescript is a so called "Superset" of JavaScript which means that all typescript code will be transpiled into usual JS code from the typescript compiler. Often those compile processes are linked with a `bundler` like `webpack`.

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/

Knowing this your error `The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type` makes a lot of sense due to a typescript file is a "non-JavaScript MIME type".

**Note:**

You can't import typescript files into javascript files, but you can do it vice versa.

Comment: "You can't import typescript files into javascript files, but you can do it vice versa." 
Not agree with your point @masserbill, we can use typescript in our javascript file.

Everything is possible in JS world.

Comment: @AzeemChauhan *Everything is possible in JS world.*. Definitley not true. As long as you make not use of `tsc` or `babel` you will not be able to parse `typescript` code. This is a simple fact.

Comment: I mostly agree, but your note ("You can't import typescript files into javascript files, but you can do it vice versa") can be a bit misleading. While it's true that you cannot import TS code with "vanilla" Node, the tools you mention enable one to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through `babel`. Follow below article

[Article: How to use typescript file in javascript project](https://www.salesscreen.com/blog/introducing-typescript-in-existing-javascript-projects-with-babel)