# Import TypeScript Module to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webstorm

I have a module in TypeScript that look as follows:

```
import { CallerId, CallScreening, CustomTagRef, MediaRef, OutboundSettings, ServiceCommon } 
from '../src/shared/domain/dto';
import { ServiceCommonEntity } from '../src/shared/domain/entity';
import { CallerIdMode, ResourceRefType } from '../src/shared/domain/enum';

export const CONTACT_PAYLOAD = 'payload';

export const ACCOUNT_PAYLOAD = 'a_payload';

export function getFakeAccountPayload() {
  return fake_payload;
}
```

In the same project I have a js file in which I want to use functions from my .ts file.

How can I import my ts module to my js file?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a .ts file for importing a .ts file?

Comment: I'm using the Dredd framework, it doesn't support typescript yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Typescript file in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410351/import-typescript-file-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we face such situation in our projects. I am pretty sure that you are migrating some part of your code to typescript and somewhere in your project you need typescript in javascript file and creating javascript file for same ts file is not way to solve the problem, but If you really want to use `typescript(.ts)` in `javascript(.js)` files, so here is the one possible solution, I am assuming that your are suing `webpack` bundler, so you use `ts-loader` and `babel-loader`  in your webpack. here are rule for your webpack configuration(Note: you must have airbnb preset, ts-loader, and all plugins installed)

```
{
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    use: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
  {
    test: /\.jsx?/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['airbnb'],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', '@babel/transform-async-to-generator', 'source-map-support', 'babel-plugin-root-import'],
        ignore: ['node_modules/is_js'],
      },
    },
    exclude: /node_modules\/(?query-string|strict-uri-encode)/,
  }
]
}
```

In case of running spec, if you are using `jest` you might also need `.babelrc` configuration for tests

```
{
  "presets": [
    "airbnb",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "plugins": ["source-map-support"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/transform-async-to-generator", "babel-plugin-root-import"],
  "ignore": ["node_modules/is_js"]
}
```

We also have one article which might be helpful. [Use .ts File .js file](https://www.salesscreen.com/blog/introducing-typescript-in-existing-javascript-projects-with-babel)