# Can a .ts file imported by a .js file, and have code completion (VS code)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Javascript project, and recently i added Typescript files to it. When i import a ts file into a js file, there is no automatic code completion or suggestions. If i try to import the build of the ts files (which are js files) i do have it (because of `checkJs:true` in `tsconfig.json`).
Is it possible to have code completion or sugggestions based on the classes imported from the .ts files?

Comment: What does "i don't have code complation" mean?

Comment: OP means "code completion", as in automatically infer variable names etc, and not "compilation", for everyone as confused as me ;)

Comment: Typescript files can't be imported into Javascript files. The other way around does work. The reason why the build files do import is that the Typescript files compile into Javascript files as you mentioned.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54410381/8129670