# Cypress fixture cannot import typescript from javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have the following two cypress fixtures.

cypress/fixtures/myFixture.js

```js
import Something from "./somewhere";

...
```

cypress/fixtures/somewhere.ts

```js
export default function Something(): number {
   return 1;
}
```

It's importing a Typescript file from JS, but it gives this error when trying to run the Cypress tests.

```
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module './somewhere' from '/path/myFixture.js'
```

I've tried adding tsconfig.json to the cypress folder like I've seen in many Stackoverflow answers, but the error is always that Cypress cannot find `somewhere.js` when it should be looking at `somewhere.ts`. I've also tried `ts-loader` to no avail and Cypress docs say it's supposed to support typescript OOTB (Cypress v10).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this question [Import Typescript file in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54410381/16997707) addresses the same issue (more generally than the Cypress context).

> TypeScript cannot be executed from a browser / node.js environment directly. At first you have to transpile it into native javascript. To do this you will need to execute tsc.

So I guess you have to take the hard path to get your JS-based Cypress project set up for Typescript. Ultimately, Cypress does not transpile by default. You *must* add typescript to get anywhere.

If I were you, I would start clean with

- install Typescript
- install Cypress, it recognizes Typescript is installed and does the TS setup for you on first start-up - `yarn cypress open` or `npx cypress open`.
- EXCEPT it fails to create a tsconfig, so will have to grab that from somewhere - probably the Cypress Real World App is an viable example.

Now you are working in typescript, copy across all the tests from the previous project.